# A coherent sheaf is a vector bundle over subvariety?

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-theory

Over a complex manifold, can every coherent sheaf be seen as a holomorphic vector bundle over an analytic subset?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what the precise question is, but consider the ideal sheaf of the origin within any higher-dimensional affine space.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that either, but given a coherent sheaf $\mathcal E$ on a complex manifold $X$, there exists a non-empty Zariski open subset $U\subset X$ such that $\mathcal E|_U$ is locally free, hence is the sheaf of sections of a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ on $U$.

Comment: Henri, do you have please a reference for that? I am quite a novice in the subject.